# popular posts for custom post type wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to display popular post for custom post type and my code is just working for post. not for custom post type.
this is my code.
in function.php i am using this

```
 function wpb_set_post_views($postID) {
    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

in the single page of custom post type i used this in my loop

```
 wpb_set_post_views(get_the_ID());
```

and in the main page where i want to display popular post of custom post type i used this

```
    <?php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'project',
  'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

 while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();


       the_title();
 endwhile
?>
```

i will be thankful to you for this kindness

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is missing a few useful things, so if it is ok for you, I would adjust your code a litte bit.

You could need a function to display the views

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0";
    }
    return $count;
}
```

In your function to count the views, you can set a cookie so only views are counted if it is not the same user.

```
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['wp_visited_ip_'.$postID])) { // check if cookie exist
            $count++; // increase counter
        }
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
        // Get IP address
        $visit_ip_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        // Set the cookie
        setcookie('wp_visited_ip_'.$postID, $visit_ip_addr, time()+ (60 * 1)); // time interval
    }
}
// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

In the single.php of your post you can call the function within the loop.

```
setPostViews(get_the_ID()); // count post views
```

The query for displaying the 5 most viewed posts could look like this:

```
        $args_fav = array(
            'post_type'         => 'project',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'meta_key'          => 'post_views_count',
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
            'post_status'       => array( 'publish' ),
            'posts_per_page'    => 5
        );

        $loop_fav = new WP_Query( $args_fav );
```

This code should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we need to do is create a function that will detect post views count and store it as a custom field for each post.

```
function wpb_set_post_views($postID) {
$count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
}else{
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
}}
//To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

In the single.php of your post, you can call the function within the loop.

```
wpb_set_post_views(get_the_ID());
```

If you want to sort the posts by view count, then you can do so easily by using the wp_query post_meta parameter. The most basic example loop query would look like this:

```
<?php 
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 
'post_type'         => ' ',// add the name for your post type
'posts_per_page' => 4, 
'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();
 
the_title();
 
endwhile;
?>
```

I hope this helps you cheers.